# Where do I control the behavior of the "X" close button in the upper right of a winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, modeless

I'm venturing into making my VB.NET application a little better to use by making some of the forms modeless.

I think I've figured out how to use dlg.Show() and dlg.Hide() instead of calling dlg.ShowDialog().  I have an instance of my modeless dialog in my main application form:

```
Public theModelessDialog As New dlgModeless
```

To fire up the modeless dialog I call

```
theModelessDialog.Show()
```

and within the OK and Cancel button handlers in `dlgModeless` I have

```
Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel_Button.Click
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

and that seems to work fine.

The "X" button in the upper right is getting me, though.  When I close the form with that button, then try to reopen the form, I get

> ObjectDisposedException was unhandled.  Cannot access a disposed object.

I feel like I'm most of the way there but I can't figure out how to do either of the following:

- Hide that "X" button
- Catch the event so I don't dispose of the object (just treat it like I hit Cancel)

Any ideas?

The class of this dialog is `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Me.Close()` to hide the form. To open it, use the following snippet:

```
If theModelessDialog.IsDisposed Then
    theModelessDialog = New dlgModeless
End If
dlgModeless.Show()
```

If this is saving data, then you'll need to figure some way of storing it (perhaps in a static variable/s in the form). This is the proper way to do what you are trying to achieve though.

You'll also have to forgive me if my VB is off, it's been a while.

Comment: Matthew, I think that's it, if I replace "Disposed" with "IsDisposed."  I tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 22):

Catch the FormClosing event and, if the reason is UserClosing, set Cancel on the event to true.

Something like the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
     Handles Form1.FormClosing

    if e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing then
        e.Cancel = true
        Me.Hide()
    end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the formclosing event allows me to do a managed exit of the form so I have included a question to confirm to exit. I also have a form flag bterminate to force the cancel where i want it to and therefore not ask the question. Thanks your suggestion helped me as well :)

```
    Dim msgboxresponse As MsgBoxResult

    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        If Not Me.bTerminate Then
            msgboxresponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to cancel adding?", _
                                MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Me.Text)
            If msgboxresponse <> MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Return
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

[@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13895/john) was Hiding the form in his code and the answers above provide a solution to that case.  Often, though, you are not planning to use the form again, so you really ***do*** want the form to be Disposed.  All Close related activities will be in one place if you Handle the FormClosing event using `Me.FormClosing` by adding it to anyCancel/Close/Exit code that you already have.  e.g. in @John's case:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
                                     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                                 Handles Cancel_Button.Click, Me.FormClosing
....More code
Me.Dispose
End Sub
```

Note the use of the `Me.Dispose` instead of any existing `Me.Close`.  If you leave the `Me.Close` you'll create an infinite loop.  See [this for the subtle differences between Close and Dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538308/using-dispose-method-instead-of-close-method-to-a-form).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with handling the FormClosing event. Or change the properties on the form to hide the system X control.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything and it didn't work
if you just want to close, without showing an messagebox, you will just need:

> Private Sub FORM1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)     Handles Me.FormClosing

```
 >e.Cancel = False
 >FORM2.Show()   (if you want to show another form)
```

> End Sub

Hope this helps you...!